# Javascript var being released early

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have a function I have used multiple times but in this one case of modifying, I seem to be missing something. I have a var `listHTML` that I am using as a base to append HTML to so I can update the HTML of a div after the for loop completes, but for whatever reason, the var's value is NULL after the for loop completes. I thought creating the reference to the var outside of the loop before the loop runs was enough to keep it in memory until the conclusion of the function...guess not.

Code:

```
var listHTML = '';

    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
    {
        var product = arr[j].split(",");
        var key = product[1];

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://domain.com/dir/get.php?key="+encodeURIComponent(key),
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            success:function(json){

                var i = 0;

                while(json[i])
                {
                    listHTML += '<div class="row">';
                    listHTML += '<div class="image"><img src="'+json[i]["image"]+'"/></div>';
                    listHTML += '<div class="title">'+json[i]["title"]+'</div>';
                    listHTML += '<div class="quantity"><input type="number" id="'+key+'" value="'+product[0]+'"/></div>';
                    listHTML += '<div class="actions"><img src="/_newsite/images/icons/trash.png" onclick="removeFromCart('+"'"+key+"'"+')" title="Remove From Cart/><img src="/_newsite/images/icons/update.png" onclick="updateCart('+"'"+key+"'"+')" title="Update Quantity"/></div>';
                    listHTML += '</div>';

                    i++;
                }

                console.log(listHTML);

            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Error");
            },
        });

    }

    console.log(listHTML);
```

When console.log is run inside the for loop, it returns the proper value I'd expect, but the one at the end of the function outside the for loop returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax success callback gets called sometime later AFTER your function finishes.  The "A" in Ajax stands for asynchronous.

Therefore `listHTML` has not been touched when your function finishes.  You need to modify `listHTML` inside the success callback function and use it there or pass it to another function as an argument that you call from within the success callback.  You can't use it outside the success handler in the way you are trying to.

Comment: Oh! Duh! That makes perfect sense! Thank you!